# PHP How to set custom headers using Curl with two levels

Tags: php, curl, soap

I am trying to create php that makes POST REQUEST to a webservice.

Having tried the service using SoapUI i know the XML POST REQUEST should look like:

```
<soapenv:Envelopexmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"xmlns:ns="http://etim.nl/xlmschemas/messageservice/2.40">
<soapenv:Header>
<ns:CustomInfo>
<ns:IsTestMessage>true</ns:IsTestMessage>
<!--Optional:-->
<ns:IsContentCompressed>false</ns:IsContentCompressed>
</ns:CustomInfo>
<ns:AuthenticationInfo>
<ns:ApplicationId>SomeId</ns:ApplicationId>
<ns:VersionId>0.9</ns:VersionId>
<ns:RelationId></ns:RelationId>
<ns:UserId>SomeUserId</ns:UserId>
<ns:Password>SomePassword</ns:Password>
</ns:AuthenticationInfo>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
<!--etc...(actual xml)-->
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How do i add the custom header in php using Curl?

Hope i am being clear enough..(btw i cant use wsdl)

Edit: No wsdl available
Edit 2:

My Current Curl:

```
<?php 

        $soapUrl = "https://services.dev-cloud.nl/services/KovraPostMessageRequestInboundProxy"; // asmx URL of WSDL
        $soapUser = "SomeUsername";  //  username
        $soapPassword = "SomePassword"; // password

        // xml post structure

$xml_post_string = '<soapenv:Body>
                    <MaintenanceStatus xmlns="http://www.gs1.nl/onderhoudstatus/insbou/001" schemaLocation="http://www.gs1.nl/onderhoudstatus/insbou/001 Onderhoudstatus_insbou001.xsd">
                    <MessageNumber>6047</MessageNumber>
                    <MessageDate>2016-08-15</MessageDate>
                    <MessageTime>08:48:39</MessageTime>
                    <InstructionData>
                    <InstructionNumber>137493.0</InstructionNumber>
                    <Status>ANN</Status>
                    <StatusDescription>Opdracht geannuleerd</StatusDescription>
                    <DateReady>2016-08-15</DateReady>
                    <FreeText>Vervallen. Doorgebeld 15-8 door Edith</FreeText>
                    <AppointmentDateTimeInformation>
                    <RequiredDeliveryDate>2016-08-17</RequiredDeliveryDate>
                    <RequiredDeliveryTime>11:00:00</RequiredDeliveryTime>
                    <DeliveryTimeFrame>
                    <DeliveryDateEarliest>2016-08-17</DeliveryDateEarliest>
                    <DeliveryTimeEarliest>11:00:00</DeliveryTimeEarliest>
                    <DeliveryDateLatest>2016-08-26</DeliveryDateLatest>
                    <DeliveryTimeLatest>00:00:00</DeliveryTimeLatest>
                    </DeliveryTimeFrame>
                    </AppointmentDateTimeInformation>
                    </InstructionData>
                    </MaintenanceStatus>
                    </soap:Body>';

            $headers = array(
                        "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"",
                        "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate",
                        "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                        "Pragma: no-cache",
                        "SOAPAction: https://services.dev-cloud.nl/services/KovraPostMessageRequestInboundProxy",
                        "Content-length: ".strlen($xml_post_string),
                        "Host: services.dev-cloud.nl",
                        "Connection: Keep-Alive",
                    );

            $url = $soapUrl;

            // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_post_string); // XML REQUEST
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

            //should i first create array?
            $CustomInfo = array();
            $CustomInfo[] = 'ns:IsTestMessage: true';
            $CustomInfo[] = 'ns:IsContentCompressed: false';

            //should i first create array?
            $AuthenticationInfo = array();
            $AuthenticationInfo[] = 'ns:ApplicationId: Reparatieverzoeken';
            $AuthenticationInfo[] = 'ns:VersionId: 0.9';
            $AuthenticationInfo[] = 'ns:RelationId:';
            $AuthenticationInfo[] = 'ns:UserId: '.$soapUser;
            $AuthenticationInfo[] = 'ns:Password: '.$soapPassword;


            $headers = array();
            $headers[] = 'ns:CustomInfo';//this is where i dont know how to go about!!!


            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);


            // converting
            $response = curl_exec($ch); 
            curl_close($ch);

            // converting
            $response1 = str_replace("<soapenv:Body>","",$response);
            $response2 = str_replace("</soapenv:Body>","",$response1);

            // convertingc to XML
            $parser = simplexml_load_string($response2); 
            print_r($parser);
?>
```

Comment: show you curl code

Comment: "btw i cant use wsdl" Why?

Comment: See my edits. The header uses nodes ie CustomInfo (with nodes) and AuthentificationInfo (with nodes). Dont have a clue how to set them...

Comment: OK, so you can use WSDL, you're just not sure how?

Comment: Yep...i have a wsdl available but it is not complete.

Comment: Your $xml_post_string would be exactly the same as the SoapUI request XML.  You're confusing http headers with SOAP headers.  SOAP headers go in the XML.  Using the wsdl will be much easier though, see __setSoapHeaders() method on the SoapClient class.